# R - What's the simple way to combine two data table element-wise?

Tags: r, paste

Table  A

| Group | varA | varB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I | 17 | 1 |
| II | 0 | 20 |

Table  B

| Group | varA | varB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I | 100.00 | 5.88 |
| II | 0.00 | 100.00 |

Table  C

| Group | varA | varB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I | 17 (100.00) | 1.00 (5.88) |
| II | 0 (0.00) | 20 (100.00) |

Is there a way to "paste" Table A + Table B into something like Table C?

Comment: Is the rowcount in both data frames same?

Comment: you mean the same number or rows? Yeah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create copy of `A` in `C` and you can achieve the desired format using `sprintf`.

```
C <- A
C[-1] <- sprintf('%d (%.2f)', as.matrix(A[-1]), as.matrix(B[-1]))
C

#  Group        varA        varB
#1     I 17 (100.00)    1 (5.88)
#2    II    0 (0.00) 20 (100.00)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(glue)
library(stringr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2 %>%
              map_if(~ is.numeric(.x), ~ glue("({.x})")) %>%
              bind_cols(), by = "Group") %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with(".x"), ~ str_c(.x, get(str_replace(cur_column(), 
                                                             "\\.x", "\\.y")), sep = " "))) %>%
  select(- ends_with(".y"))

  Group   varA.x   varB.x
1     I 17 (100) 1 (5.88)
2    II    0 (0) 20 (100)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
C <- A %>%
      mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~
        str_c(., "(", round(B[[cur_column()]], 2), ")")))
```

---

Or may use `sprintf`

```
C <- A %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), 
        ~sprintf("%d (%.2f)", ., B[[cur_column()]])))
```

#### data

```
A <- structure(list(Group = c("I", "II"), varA = c(17L, 0L), varB = c(1L, 
20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

B <- structure(list(Group = c("I", "II"), varA = c(100, 0), varB = c(5.88, 
100)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R option using `Map` + `list2DF`

```
> list2DF(c(A[1], Map(function(x, y) sprintf("%d (%.2f)", x, y), A[-1], B[-1])))
  Group        varA        varB
1     I 17 (100.00)    1 (5.88)
2    II    0 (0.00) 20 (100.00)
```